# Drawing the squares of a grid in UIView, the alpha of the fill color of UIBezierPath is inconsistent depending on the square location

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uibezierpath

I was trying to achieve something similar to a chess board. In my class, which inherits from UIView, I'm drawing all the squares of the grid using two nested for loops when overriding the `draw()` method.

I also want to have some visual indicator when the finger is dragged inside the grid, so I want to draw on top of the selected square another yellow square with an `alpha` equal to `0.15`.

The issue is that, depending on the square location, the `alpha` property seems to be more or less ignored. In particular, the more you drag up left, the more the `alpha` of the yellow square tends to `1`, the more you go down right the more is respected.

See the gif example [here](https://imgur.com/a/cNFOM7B). To better visualize the issue, in this example all the squares are gray, but they should actually be like a chess board.

My `drawSquare()` method, called in `draw()`:

```
private func drawSquare(col: Int, row: Int, color: UIColor, isSelected: Bool) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: CGFloat(col) * cellSide, y: CGFloat(row) * cellSide, width: cellSide, height: cellSide))
    color.setFill()
    path.fill(with: .normal, alpha: isSelected ? 0.15 : 1.0)
    
    // or also
    // let colorWithAlpha = color.withAlphaComponent(isSelected ? 0.15 : 1.0)
    // colorWithAlpha.setFill()
    // path.fill()
}
```

Down below there is a runnable, simplified sample of my `BoardView` class. I'm still learning, so for sure I'm missing something here. What is my mistake? Maybe something related to the way the drawings are performed under the hood? How can I achieve a yellow square with my set `alpha` consistent for each square?

```
import UIKit

final class BoardView: UIView {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    private var cellSide: CGFloat = CGFloat.zero
    private var fromCol: Int?
    private var fromRow: Int?
    private var toCol: Int?
    private var toRow: Int?
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    // MARK: - Draw
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        cellSide = bounds.width / 8
        drawBoard()
    }
    private func drawBoard() {
        for row in 0..<4 {
            for col in 0..<4 {
                drawSquare(col: col * 2, row: row * 2, color: UIColor.gray, isSelected: false)
                drawSquare(col: 1 + col * 2, row: row * 2, color: UIColor.gray, isSelected: false)
                drawSquare(col: col * 2, row: 1 + row * 2, color: UIColor.gray, isSelected: false)
                drawSquare(col: 1 + col * 2, row: 1 + row * 2, color: UIColor.gray, isSelected: false)
                if let fromCol = fromCol, let fromRow = fromRow {
                    drawSquare(col: fromCol, row: fromRow, color: .yellow, isSelected: true)
                }
                if let toCol = toCol, let toRow = toRow {
                    drawSquare(col: toCol, row: toRow, color: .yellow, isSelected: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func drawSquare(col: Int, row: Int, color: UIColor, isSelected: Bool) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: CGFloat(col) * cellSide, y: CGFloat(row) * cellSide, width: cellSide, height: cellSide))
        color.setFill()
        path.fill(with: .normal, alpha: isSelected ? 0.15 : 1.0)
        
        // or also
        // let colorWithAlpha = color.withAlphaComponent(isSelected ? 0.15 : 1.0)
        // colorWithAlpha.setFill()
        // path.fill()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Touches
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if let first = touches.first {
            let fingerLocation = first.location(in: self)
            fromCol = Int(fingerLocation.x / cellSide)
            fromRow = Int(fingerLocation.y / cellSide)
            // intentionally not calling setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        if let first = touches.first {
            let fingerLocation = first.location(in: self)
            toCol = Int(fingerLocation.x / cellSide)
            toRow = Int(fingerLocation.y / cellSide)
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if let first = touches.first {
            fromCol = nil
            fromRow = nil
            self.toCol = nil
            self.toRow = nil
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be drawing an 8x8 grid but you only iterate through 4x4. You then draw 4 gray squares in each of those 16 bigger squares. While that means less iterating, it means far more complicated code and code duplication.

The big issue is that you draw a yellow square at `fromRow`/`fromCol` 16 times and a yellow square at `toRow`/`fromRow` 16 times. Shouldn't you check `row` and `col` with `fromRow`, `toRow`, and `fromCol`, `toCol` so you only draw a yellow square once in any given square?

I think you want the following for `drawBoard`:

```swift
private func drawBoard() {
    for row in 0..<8 {
        for col in 0..<8 {
            drawSquare(col: col, row: row, color: UIColor.gray, isSelected: false)

            if let fromCol, let fromRow, let toCol, let toRow, fromCol <= col && col <= toCol, fromRow <= row && row <= toRow {
                // We have start and end and the current square is within the range
                drawSquare(col: col, row: row, color: .yellow, isSelected: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above works because you are not calling `setNeedsDisplay` until you have set all of `fromCol`, `fromRow`, `toCol`, and `toRow`.

If you want the first yellow square to appear as soon as the user touches the screen and not wait until the user starts to move their finger, then update `touchesBegan` as follows:

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    if let first = touches.first {
        let fingerLocation = first.location(in: self)
        fromCol = Int(fingerLocation.x / cellSide)
        fromRow = Int(fingerLocation.y / cellSide)
        toCol = fromCol
        toRow = fromRow
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to highlight just one small square at the time. But as you stated solving my issue, and as I had not noticed, I was drawing the yellow square multiple times, I misplaced my code inside the loop. :/ The difference in alpha, which is now explained as multiple overlapping drawings not always rendered, mislead me into thinking the issue were somewhere else, I hadn't double checked the drawBoard logic, oops. Thanks!